# How to get all sibling div's inside overlapping div area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a large div and smaller siblings divs positioned inside it like this:

```css
.large{
  height:20rem;
  width:20rem;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
}

.item1{
  height:5rem;
  width:5rem;
  background-color:blue;
  top:1rem;
  position:absolute;
}

.item2{
  height:5rem;
  width:5rem;
  background-color:green;
  top:3rem;
  left:2rem;
  position:absolute;
}

.item3{
  height:5rem;
  width:5rem;
  background-color:yellow;
  top:1rem;
  left:6rem;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="large"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item3"></div>
```

How do I get all the small divs within the large div dimensions?
Is there something similar to `elementsFromPoint`? Maybe something like `elementsFromArea`

**Edit:**

assume `.large` spans 320 pixels x 320 pixels
and I have multiple smaller divs on my screen, which can either be overlapping `.large` or outside it

How do I find divs which are overlapping `.large`?

Maybe we could get the position of `.large` & we already have the height and width of it and add it to some function like this:

```
elementsFromArea(large_x,large_y,large_height,large_width);
```

This should return an array of all the divs within that given range

(`.large` is merely for reference sake, I simply want to pass any given square area & find all the divs lying within it )

**Bounty Edit:**

The solution provided by @A Haworth works but I'm looking for a solution which doesn't involve having to loop and check every single element

this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tL7mjpua/19/) explains what I'm ultimately trying to achieve

Any clever work around will be accepted too!

Comment: Hi.Dou you want to cover these small divs with large?

Comment: What to you mean 'get'? Are you trying to make a javascript reference to them to allow manipulation? Also, all of the divs are siblings, the smaller ones only appear on top of (not inside) the large ones because they are all positioned absolutely within the body. Some clarification is needed, it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @HazratGafulov no I want to find which divs are overlapping large

Comment: @DavePritlove I've made an edit to the question, please let me know if it's more clear now?

Comment: I can't see how to do exactly this (find all elements, whether or not children of large that overlap it) without a loop, but perhaps if you could describe more what you want to do with that information there may be workarounds. For example, if you wanted to change the color of the overlap bit.

Comment: @AHaworth I'm trying to get all the elements inside the frame as given in the fiddle example and when I say 'without a loop' i mean not having to check every single element everytime the frame changes

Comment: I think @AHaworth rather wants to know the broader context of what functionality you're trying to build with this. What does your app do with these elements, once it has them? Do changes happen once, on page load? Or are the positions of the small elements constantly changing?

Comment: @inwerpsel well this is a smaller example of a bigger project I'm working on, basically the smaller elements can change position by drag and drop, but ultimately I'll be invoking a function to get all the elements inside either when the frame moves or any single element is moved out of the frame

Answer (score 4):

You can use getBoundingClientRect to find the left, right, top and bottom bounds of each element.

Then test whether there is overlap with the large element by seeing whether the left is to the left of the right side of the large element and so on:

```
if ( ((l <= Right) && (r >= Left)) && ( (t <= Bottom) && (b >= Top)) )
```

To give a more thorough test, in this snippet the blue element has been pushed down so it only partially overlaps the large one and the yellow element doesn't overlap at all.

```js
const large = document.querySelector('.large');
const largeRect = large.getBoundingClientRect();
const Left = largeRect.left;
const Right = largeRect.right;
const Top = largeRect.top;
const Bottom = largeRect.bottom;
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.large ~ *');
let overlappers = [];
items.forEach(item => {
  const itemRect = item.getBoundingClientRect();
  const l = itemRect.left;
  const r = itemRect.right;
  const t = itemRect.top;
  const b = itemRect.bottom;
  if (((l <= Right) && (r >= Left)) && ((t <= Bottom) && (b >= Top))) {
    overlappers.push(item);
  }
});
console.log('The items with these background colors overlap the large element:');
overlappers.forEach(item => {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(item).backgroundColor);
});
```

```css
.large {
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.item1 {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 19rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.item2 {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: green;
  top: 3rem;
  left: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.item3 {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 26rem;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="large"></div>
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```

Note, this snippet tests only those elements which are siblings of large in the CSS sense, that is that follow large. If you want all siblings whether they follow large or come before it then go back up to large's parent and get all its children (which will of course include large).

Comment: huh I thought there would be some inbuilt method for this but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) describes exactly what you are looking for. It's a relatively new API so I'm not surprised the other answers have not referenced it.

I have personally used it in a lazy loading context for displaying large tables without rendering 9001 rows at once. In my case, I would use the IntersectionObserver to determine when the last table row was in the user's field of view, and then I would load additional rows. It's very performant as it doesn't require any loops that poll the position of DOM elements, and the browser is free to optimize it however it likes.

Stealing from MDN, here's a simple way to create an IntersectionObserver. I've commented out options which I don't think you need.

```
    let options = {
        root: document.querySelector('.large'),
        // rootMargin: '0px',
        // threshold: 1.0
    }
    
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

The callback is a function that fires whenever an element's intersection of `.large` changes by a certain threshold. If threshold = 0 (the default value and what I think you want in your case), then it will fire even if only 1 pixel overlaps.

Once you've created an IntersectionObserver with `.large` as the root, you will then want to `.observe()` the smaller divs so the IntersectionObserver can report on when they intersect `.large`.

Again, stealing from MDN, the format of the callback is as follows. Please note that the callback fires on **intersection changes**, meaning that if a smaller div that used to intersect `.large` no longer does, it will be in the list of entries. To get elements that are intersecting `.large` you will want to filter `entries` such that only those where `entry.isInterecting === true` are present. From the filtered list of `entries` you can then grab `entry.target` from every entry.

```
    let callback = (entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
            // target element:
            //   entry.boundingClientRect
            //   entry.intersectionRatio
            //   entry.intersectionRect
            //   entry.isIntersecting
            //   entry.rootBounds
            //   entry.target
            //   entry.time
        });
    };
```

Comment: Hi, yes I've used IntersectionObserver quite a lot and it can be very useful but I don't really see how it stops the need for a loop. You'll have to loop over all elements putting an observer on them. This the means you'll get informed if things change dynamically which is a plus, but in what way does it prevent needing a loop?

Comment: this seems to be what I'm looking for but I have no idea how it works, could you maybe use with the example fiddle I've given?

Comment: I tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pdcn3umg/31/) but I'm having problem understand the root option

Comment: Since the elements that need to be observed are **siblings and not descendants** of `.frame`, this won't work. It also explains what the root option does.

Comment: As @inwerpsel has pointed out, this answer is not correct. IntersectionObserver reports on intersections with an ancestor, not on any random element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API for more detail on this.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution provided by @A Haworth works but I'm looking for a solution which doesn't involve having to loop and check every single element

I don't know how to achieve this without a loop, if we are handle an array of elements, but you can test this solution with the `resizeObserver` and **loops**.

```js
// Init elements
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
const frame = document.getElementById('frame');

const resultElement = document.getElementById('for-result');

// Creating an array of properties
// Math.trunc() removing any fractional digits
const itemsProperties = items.map(item => {
  return {
    width: item.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    height: item.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    x: Math.trunc(item.getBoundingClientRect().x),
    y: Math.trunc(item.getBoundingClientRect().y),
  };
});

function within_frame(frameSize) {
  const inside = [];
  for (const i in itemsProperties) {
    // Determine current height and width of the square
    // Because X, Y is TOP, LEFT, and we need RIGHT, BOTTOM values.
    const positionY = itemsProperties[i].height + itemsProperties[i].y;
    const positionX = itemsProperties[i].width + itemsProperties[i].x;

    // If the position square less than or equal to the size of the inner frame,
    // then we will add values to the array.
    if (
      positionY <= frameSize.blockSize &&
      positionX <= frameSize.inlineSize
    ) {
      inside.push(itemsProperties[i]);
    }
  }
  //returns all the elements within the frame bounds
  return inside;
}

// Initialize observer
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  // Determine height and width of the 'frame'
  const frameSize = entries[0].borderBoxSize[0];
  // Return an array of values inside  'frame'
  const result = within_frame(frameSize);
  //console.log(result);
  
  // for result
  resultElement.innerHTML = result.map(
    (el, idx) => `<code>square${idx + 1} position: ${el.x}px x ${el.y}px</code>`
  );
});
// Call an observer to watch the frame
resizeObserver.observe(frame);
```

```css
#frame {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  display: inline-block;
  resize: both;
  border: solid black 0.5rem;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.item {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
}


/* for result */
pre {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0.5rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
#for-result {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame"></div>

<div class="item" style="background-color: red"></div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: green; top: 50%"></div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: blue; top: 20%; left: 30%"></div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: pink; top: 60%; left: 20%"></div>
<div class="item" style="background-color: yellow; top: 25%; left: 10%"></div>

<pre id="for-result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Heads up: A frivolous and probably useless answer

However the question itself seems quite frivolous too. No real world use case has been provided yet and I can't think of any either. Similarly, in theory my answer could be useful, but you're more likely struck by an asteroid than finding yourself needing it.

The point of posting is more that it provides some perspective on the performance of the other proposed solution. You can see you need at least hundreds of elements before performance starts being a concern.

My "answer" only works if:

- items are rectangles
- items cannot overlap

#### The potential "performance problem"

Perhaps [the "not a loop" requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580370/how-to-get-all-sibling-divs-inside-overlapping-div-area?noredirect=1#comment129021406_72580370) refers to having a solution that doesn't require you to loop through a potentially large amount of other items in JS? This could be a valid concern, if the number of items can ever get really large.

Say that the area you're testing is relatively small compared to the items, and there are thousands of items that may or may not be inside, looping all of them might be relatively costly. Especially if you need to give each an event listener.

As already pointed out, it would be nice if a native API similar to `document.getElementFromPoint` existed, as that would undoubtedly be more performant than implementing in JS.

However that API does not exist. Probably because nobody ever found themselves needing it in a real world use case.

#### Sampling points of the frame

Now you could just use the `document.ElementFromPoint` API on every single point of the frame. However that would scale even worse with the frame's size.

But do we need to check every point to guarantee we're detecting all elements? Not if the elements can't overlap: since the smallest element is likely still many pixels high and wide, we could create a grid of points with those minimum values. As long as the elements don't have changing dimensions (or they can only grow) we only need to loop them once (to determine the smallest), not on updates. *Note I do loop them every time, to account for setting changes. If you're sure elements have fixed dimensions you only need it once at the start of your script.*

Of course, you do now have to loop over points instead. However...

In the best case scenario, where the minimum element is equally wide and high (or bigger), you only need to check 4 points. In fact I used this in a function to generate random cubes, to avoid overlap with earlier cubes.

It doesn't work on overlapping elements as `document.ElementFromPoint` only knows about the topmost. You could work around that by temporarily setting a `z-index`, but I had to stop somewhere.

#### Does it perform better?

I'm not sure at all whether this would ever make sense to do, but I don't immediately see another way to handle large amounts of items.

In the best case of needing just 4 points (small area to check overlap), it's hard to imagine another approach being faster, if the other approach needs to go through thousands of elements in JS. Even with up to a few tens of points it'll probably still be "fast" regardless of how many elements on the page.

```js
let allItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
const frame = document.getElementById('frame')

function measureLoop() {
  const start = performance.now();
  const large = document.querySelector('#frame');
  const largeRect = large.getBoundingClientRect();
  const Left = largeRect.left;
  const Right = largeRect.right;
  const Top = largeRect.top;
  const Bottom = largeRect.bottom;
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('#frame ~ *');
  let overlappers = [];
  items.forEach(item => {
    const itemRect = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    const l = itemRect.left;
    const r = itemRect.right;
    const t = itemRect.top;
    const b = itemRect.bottom;
    if (((l <= Right) && (r >= Left)) && ((t <= Bottom) && (b >= Top))) {
      overlappers.push(item);
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('result-loop').innerHTML = overlappers.length;
  document.getElementById('time-loop').innerHTML = performance.now() - start;
}

function randomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function within_frame(frame, items) {
  const rect = frame.getBoundingClientRect();
  const frameX = rect.left;
  const frameY = rect.top;
  const frameWidth = frame.clientWidth;
  const frameHeight = frame.clientHeight;
  const smallestWidth = Math.min(...(items.map(i => i.clientWidth)));
  const smallestHeight = Math.min(...(items.map(i => i.clientHeight)));

  const set = new Set();
  let points = 0;
  const lastY = frameHeight + smallestHeight;
  const lastX = frameWidth + smallestWidth;
  for (let y = 0; y < lastY; y += smallestHeight) {
    for (let x = 0; x < lastX; x += smallestWidth) {
      points++;
      const checkX = Math.min(frameX + x, rect.right)
      const checkY = Math.min(frameY + y, rect.bottom)
      // Note there is always a result, but sometimes it's not the elements we're looking for.
      // Set takes care of only storing unique, so we can loop a small amount of elements at the end and filter.
      set.add(document.elementFromPoint(checkX, checkY));
    }
  }
  set.forEach(el => (el === frame || el === document.documentElement || !items.includes(el)) && set.delete(el))

  document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = points;

  return set;
}

function measure() {
  // Frame needs to be on top for resizing, put it below while calculating.
  frame.style.zIndex = 1;
  const start = performance.now();
  const result = within_frame(frame, allItems)
  const duration = performance.now() - start
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = [...result.entries()].length;
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = duration;
  // Restore.
  frame.style.zIndex = 3;
}

document.getElementById('measure').addEventListener('click', () => {measure(); measureLoop();})


const overlapsExisting = (el) => {
  return within_frame(el, allItems);
}

let failedGenerated = 0;

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function spawnCubes() {
  frame.style.zIndex = 1;

  allItems.forEach(item => item.parentNode.removeChild(item));
  const nPoints = document.getElementById('nCubes').value;
  const cubeSize = document.getElementById('size').value;

  let newItems = [];
  let failedGenerated = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nPoints && failedGenerated < 1000; i++) {
    // Sleep so that stuff is drawn.
    if ((i + failedGenerated) % 100 === 0) {
      document.getElementById('nCubes').value = newItems.length;
      await sleep(0);
    }
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'item';
    //el.innerHTML = i;
    el.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    el.style.top = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 90)}%`;
    el.style.left = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 60)}%`;
    el.style.width = `${cubeSize}px`;
    el.style.height = `${cubeSize}px`;

    frame.after(el);

    const existingOverlapping = within_frame(el, newItems);

    if (existingOverlapping.size > 0) {
      i--;
      failedGenerated++;
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
      continue;
    }
    newItems.push(el);
  }
  console.log('failedAttempts', failedGenerated);
  allItems = newItems;
  frame.style.zIndex = 3;
  document.getElementById('nCubes').value = newItems.length;
}
frame.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {measure(); measureLoop()});


spawnCubes().then(() => {measure(); measureLoop();});
document.getElementById('randomize').addEventListener('click', e => {
  spawnCubes().then(measure);
})
```

```css
#frame {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  resize: both;
  border: solid black 0.1rem;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.item {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.controls {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame"></div>



<div class="controls">
  <button id="measure">
    measure
  </button>
  <button id="randomize">
    spawn cubes
  </button>

  <div>
    N cubes:
    <input id="nCubes" type="number" value="40">
  </div>
  <div>
    Cube size:
    <input id="size" type="number" value="16">
  </div>

  <div>
    N inside large:
    <span id="result">

    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Time (ms):
    <span id="time">

    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Points:
    <span id="points">

    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    N inside large (loop):
    <span id="result-loop">

    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Time (ms) (loop):
    <span id="time-loop">

    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```